# R{beepr} error in beepr package in R

Tags: r, package, beep

I installed the "beepr" package like a month ago to warn me when I finished a long script. I worked perfectly until now.
I don't know why when I call the function in Rstudio it prints an error:

> beep(9)

```
Please use (fixed|coll|regexp)(x, ignore_case = TRUE) instead of ignore.case(x)
Please use (fixed|coll|regexp)(x, ignore_case = TRUE) instead of ignore.case(x)
Warning message:
In value[[3L]](cond) :
  beep() could not play the sound due to the following error:
Error in play.default(x, rate, ...): no audio drivers are available
```

I don't know what's the difference between before and now. Any suggestions in order to solve this problem?

R version 3.0.2

OS:"x86_64, linux-gnu"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exerience here. Digging into the code, it turns out that the problem is related to the `is_wav_fname` function, which uses the deprecated `ignore.case(...)` function.

If you replace:

```
str_detect(fname, ignore.case("\.wav$"))
```

... with:

```
str_detect(fname, fixed(".wav", ignore_case=TRUE))
```

... it will fix the problem. I've posted the issue on the author's GitHub page with a fix proposal; see https://github.com/rasmusab/beepr/issues/11